# Tee::FlushToDisk : Timeout flushing queued prints

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu, tee

I'm running a program which generates a log file on Ubuntu 12.04. The log file is sometimes complete, and sometimes it's cut off at random places. I see this error "Tee::FlushToDisk : Timeout flushing queued prints".
I'm not calling tee explicitly, but I am calling program and I don't know if it uses Tee in the program. And no, I'm doing this locally.

What does this mean? Google doesn't even return anything.

Comment: Are you using this script on a remote connection ?

Comment: Is the log generated by `tee`? What if you just print it out directly?

Comment: The log is not generated by tee. I'm actually running this on a Android device, and I'm using adb to pull this log.